# Is it possible to change the navigation bar title outside of viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to change the navigation bar title with this statement:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:myTitle];
```

It works fine in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but it doesn't work anywhere else.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  It's a view controller I'm working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very simple way to change the title for the current view controller.

```
self.title = @"New Title";
```

Calling this on a view controller that is in a navigation controller will result in the title shown in the navigation bar being updated with the new title.

This can be called at any time while the view controller is displayed.

There is no need to dig into the view controller's `navigationItem` for setting the title.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't change the title even though the view controller is being displayed.  I don't think I know what you mean when you say "view controller that is in a navigation controller".  Please explain.

Comment: Are you adding your view controller to a `UINavigationController` or did you simply add a `UINavigationBar` to your view controller?

Comment: I assume I am adding my view controller to a navigation controller, since this is how I am invoking it from another view controller: [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sentenceViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In my own app and a simple test I app I created, calling `self.title = @"Some title"` worked just fine changing the title of the current view controller. If it's not working for your then there must be something else going on.

Comment: Can you make any guesses about what might be causing it to be impossible to update the title outside of viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear?

Comment: I can't even guess what might cause this not to work. It might help to show some of your relevant code.

Comment: I figured it out. I was updating the title with the original setting after I updated it with the new setting.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I wanted to answer this for future users. I think the main issue that most answers don't cover is that it is important to set the title from the main thread, otherwise there are a handful of cases where it won't get set immediately. For Swift 3.0 you can use code like this:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.title = "Example string"
 }
```

It is important to do all UI updates from the main thread. I'm not sure if the original user was setting the title via an asynchronous closure, but this should help anyone who is having difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the view controller's title property that the navigationItem will use.  The answer above is the simplest and correct way to change the title in the navigation bar.

If you need to customize your navigation bar, the way you do this is to override it in your UIViewController subclass, NOT change it in viewDidAppear: or any other viewWill/Did methods

```
- (UINavigationItem*)navigationItem
{
  UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [super navigationItem];

  // customize it further than the default

  return navigationItem;
}
```

In addition, you can have changes in your title update a custom titleView using KVO.  You listen for changes in the UIViewController's title property and update the titleView property of your navigationItem.  Check this out:

```
static void *kObjectStateObservingContext = &kObjectStateObservingContext;  // outside your @implementation bit

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // other init stuff here...

        [self addObserver: self forKeyPath:@"title" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: kObjectStateObservingContext];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver: self forKeyPath:@"title"];
}
```

And now we revisit the navigationItem again, where you can create a custom UILabel that will update whenever we change the title, and after that we have to provide a handler implementation for when the title does change:

```
- (UINavigationItem*)navigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [super navigationItem];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(roundf((320 - 230)/2), 0, 230, 44)];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 18];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topnav-background-text-gradient.png"]];  // you can even draw the font with a gradient!
    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha:0.59];
    titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0);
    titleLabel.text = self.title;
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;

    return navigationItem;
}
```

And finally, what to do when self.title actually changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ( context == kObjectStateObservingContext ) {
        // here we update the text of the titleView
        if ([self.navigationItem.titleView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [(UILabel*)self.navigationItem.titleView setText: self.title];
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

And there you go!  Obviously a bit more code than you might have thought, so if you're not currently, I recommend to anyone building iOS Apps that you always create a base class view controller for your application, (MyBaseViewController : UIViewController) then subclass that for any other view controllers in your app.

Comment: As of iOS 5.0 you can simply make use of the appearance APIs for `UINavigationBar`. There is no need for any of this code you posted (as of iOS 5.0).

Comment: Since the only thing you changed is the `textColor`, make use of the `UINavigationBar titleTextAttributes` method. If you want the change made to every nav bar in the app, call `[UINavigationBar appearance].titleTextAttributes = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the the title in `viewDidLoad`, because the view is not yet visible but instaciated. Same story for `viewWillAppear`. After the `UIElement` is visible, you cant change the title without a `redraw`.

Comment: I tried: [self.view setNeedsDisplay];  after changing the navigation bar title, but that did not change the title.

Comment: I also tried: [self.navigationItem.titleView setNeedsDisplay];   That didn't work either.

Comment: hm. you could try to read out the title of the navigationitem after you changed it and make sure the new title was set actually.

Comment: try to NSLog(@"title: %@", self.navigationItem.title);

Answer (score 0):

@reid55 you can set navigation title in below method also:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
   [[self navigationItem] setTitle:myTitle];
}
return self;
}
```